# Appending data to new row without changing previous one and index number pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So i am scraping stock price data every 10 minutes from a website right now i am recording it using the below code to excel.

```
dataframe.to_excel('pricedata.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter', header=True, index=True)
```

as price changes every 10 minutes i want to append it to previous excel without changing the index number like below

```
      Price       Time
0       20       01:00
0       25       01:10
0       23       01:20
0       27       01:30
```

what i don't want when scraping data every 10 minutes

```
      Price       Time
0       20       01:00
1       25       01:10
2       23       01:20
3       27       01:30
```

Comment: Create a new column with value 0 and change your code to `index=False`

Comment: Pandas index should be unique. 
Would be good to know why you want this. 
If it's just a 0 column, try to append with an 'index' column being 0 and set index=False in your dataframe.to_excel().

Comment: Hey @Zac, You can `read_excel` & store it in a variable `df1`. Read from website & store it in another variable `df2`. Do concatenation `df = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)` and Finally save `df.to_excel('SAME_NAME.xlsx', index=False)`

Comment: @AjayA, Thanks for your answer it works but now only issue i have is when it concatenate previous index column is add at the end, from the first file.example if first file has index number 1,2,3 when concatenate next time i has 1,2,3,4 as index but new column at the end appears automatically as noname with rows 1,2,3

Comment: Those are called `index` and is supposed to remain unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3], 'b': [4]})
s = df.xs(0).copy()

s.name = 0
s['a'] = 5
s['b'] = 6

df = df.append(s)
print(df)
```

```
   a  b
0  3  4
0  5  6
```